# Android: Hide/show or add/remove fragments

Tags: android

```
case R.id.section:
int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
FrameLayout FragmentContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.FragmentContainer);

switch (orientation) {
case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
    if (FragmentContainer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(new FragmentOne()).commit();
    } else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.FragmentContainer, new FragmentOne()).commit();
    }
    break;

case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
    if (FragmentContainer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(new FragmentTwo()).commit();
    } else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.FragmentContainer, new FragmentTwo()).commit();
    }
    break;
}
```

I am trying to remove/add fragments based on the visibility of my framelayout, but when i click on the menu item, nothing happens...

Below is my Frame layout defined in XML.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/FragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
     />
```

I have tried both `add and replace` methods of the fragment.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @AndroidAddict: no, i hope i am doing the right way...

Comment: Is your menu event firing?

Comment: I'm not trying to sound condescending, but it would be very helpful to know what you have tried to resolve the issue and what you know about the situation.

Comment: @AndroidAddict: you are right, just placed loggers on the if/else part of orientation-landscape to check whether one of them is getting called.

Comment: I will move to answer then.

Comment: Is your menu event firing? If your menu is not firing that would explain why nothing is happening.

Comment: Its getting fired, but is not able to add the fragment... Here is my logger Log.d("Its fired","Its getting in add"); The else part is getting called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `framelayout` has `android:visibility="gone"`. On the code i don't see `FragmentContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Just make changes to both of your if/else conditons...

```
if (FragmentContainer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(new FragmentOne()).commit();
    FragmentContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   } else {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.FragmentContainer, new FragmentOne()).commit();
    FragmentContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```